# Replace applet with alternatives

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet, applet-servlet

Our app heavily makes use of applets to check-in (upload) and check out (download) files from users machine. Can someone please confirm what are the alternatives for applet (as it is going to be deprecated by Oracle in 2018)?

Comment: What part of the task cannot be completed using JS?

Comment: JS cannot access user's machines hard disc which signed applet can. Can someone pls suggest alternative for applet. Through jnlp can we access user's hard disc.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We were using applets in our web application for printing, scanning etc. on local machines. We solved the problem with a simple Java Web Start client application that has a simple web server embedded (Jetty). Now when user starts the web application the client application is downloaded, if necessary, and started on the local machine. It sits there in a tray and listens for requests from the server side application. Handlers are implemented for different types of requests. When client side receives a request, it hands it over to a responsible handler, which executes its task and creates a response, that is sent back to the server side.
For now, this solution works perfect and we could reuse most of the applet code.